# Premissions to access LDAP from a windows service

Tags: c#, permissions, ldap

I'm building a windows service that polls a windows file share location for a file containing members that may be found in LDAP. The windows service is running as a specific user on the domain to have access to the file share.  This user is in the Administrator group both on the server running the service and where LDAP is found.

The problem I have is that fetching the files works fine but then when accessing LDAP I get the following exception:

> LDAPService.Program - Exception: An operations error occurred. 
>                           InnerEx:
>
> === STACKTRACE === 
>   LDAPService.Program -    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.RefreshCache()
>
> === BASE EXC === 
>   LDAPService.Program - System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072020): An operations error occurred.

Searching for this error there is a lot about ASP.NET and using `Impersonate()`. But that didn't help.

If I change the windows service to logon as Local System Account then I have no problems accessing LDAP (but I can't access the windows file share).

What other settings should I look at?

Comment: sounds like you need to have an admin setup your application with a system account this sounds like a permissions issue when you log in or run the application locally of course your network creds will be recognized if you are in AD or LDAP but LDAP knows nothing about the application when it's running on a different machine.. also do you have or use any Domain/User login with the application..? and I would actually stay away from `Impersonate` doesn't sound like a secure mechanism via the web..

Answer (score 0):

I was using two different LDAP directories and forgot to provide the user/pass for the second one. Had only given it for the first one.

A classic example of what we call SBS here in Sweden (Skit Bakom Spakarna).